# Use of fill_between with pandadataframe, need help i get the following error ValueError: Argument dimensions are incompatible

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, matplotlib

I am trying to fill the area between the record high and record low temperatures using fill_between, below is my code but when I try to use d, Max_Plot2005_2014_array, Min_Plot2005_2014_array to fill the area I get an error. I am new to python, so I don't know what I might be doing wrong.
Thanks for advising!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import calendar  
from datetime import datetime

ax = plt.gca()

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
    
df= pd.read_csv('data/C2A2_data/BinnedCsvs_d400/fb441e62df2d58994928907a91895ec62c2c42e6cd075c2700843b89.csv')

df.rename(columns={'Data_Value':'Temp_Celcius'}, inplace=True)

df.rename(columns={'Date':'Year'}, inplace=True)

df['Temp_Celcius']=0.1*df['Temp_Celcius']

df['Year']=pd.to_datetime(df['Year'], format='%Y-%m-%d')

year2005_2014_day29mask= (df['Year'].map(lambda x: x.year) != 2015) & (df['Year'].map(lambda x: x.day) != 29)

year2015_mask=df['Year'].map(lambda x: x.year) == 2015

Plot2005_2014=df[year2005_2014_day29mask]

Plot2005_2014=Plot2005_2014.drop_duplicates(subset=(['Year', 'Temp_Celcius']), keep='first')

Plot2015=df[year2015_mask]

Plot2015=Plot2015.drop_duplicates(subset=(['Year', 'Temp_Celcius']), keep='first')

Max_Plot2005_2014=Plot2005_2014.groupby(['Element','Year']).max()

Min_Plot2005_2014=Plot2005_2014.groupby(['Element','Year']).min()

Max_Plot2005_2014.reset_index().plot(figsize=(15,10), title='High and low temperatures over the period 2005-2014', x ='Year', y='Temp_Celcius', kind = 'line', color='red', ax=ax)
Min_Plot2005_2014.reset_index().plot(figsize=(15,10), title='High and low temperatures over the period 2005-2014', x ='Year', y='Temp_Celcius', kind = 'line', color='blue', ax=ax)

ax.legend(["Temp_Max", "Temp_Min"])

d= Plot2005_2014['Year'].values

Max_Plot2005_2014_array=Max_Plot2005_2014['Temp_Celcius'].values
Min_Plot2005_2014_array=Min_Plot2005_2014['Temp_Celcius'].values

plt.gca().fill_between(d,Max_Plot2005_2014_array,Min_Plot2005_2014_array, facecolor='blue',alpha=0.25) 

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One detail which raises suspicion is that:

- as the *x* axis you use *Year* column from the **whole** DataFrame,
- but the source to *y* axis you use the result of grouping, so the number
  of elements is smaller than in the source for *x* axis.

What also raises suspicion, is that your grouping is on *two* columns.

So, to sum up, check how many elements you have in *x* axis
and in both sources for *y* axis (the curves to draw).

Indicate also **which row** caused the mentioned exception.
I suppose that it occurred **earlier** than the mentioned *fill_between*.

And the last remark:
You presented a piece of code how you generate DataFrames,
but without source data we still aren't able to replicate your computation.
You had better provided the content of *Max_Plot2005_2014*,
*Min_Plot2005_2014* and *d* (actually, smaller samples, but causing the same
exception).

Comment: Thank you, I was able to resolve the issue based on your feedback